# Taylor Series inverse function

Tags: calculus, functions, summation, taylor-expansion

Find a function represented by the Taylor series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\cdot\dfrac{3^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\cdot x^{2k}$.

This series looks very similar to the result for sin 3x. However, it has an extra x. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$ and pull an $x$ into the infinite sum

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{x}\sin(3x)$. We get an extra $x$ in our series that way.